# Angular5 HttpClient send data but server can not understand its params

Tags: angular, http, angular5, angular-httpclient

When I submit a regular HTML form, My back-end service ( written in Laravel ) can understand POST parameters.

I checked the request header in the browser. Request parameters are:

```
Form Data:
    _token:v4xCN9fHMpZhoQMGHfbqI01XDsQ1nCxYhy3RDrw5
    username:root
    password:123456
```

Then I wrote the following method to send a post request to the server via angular5 `HttpClient`:

```
public post(url: string, data: any): Observable<any[]> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
    return this.http.post( url, data,
        {
            headers: headers
        }
    ).pipe(
        tap(success => this.handleSuccess(success)),
        catchError(this.handleError())
    );
}
```

But browser displays a different Form Data like this:

```
Form Data:
    {"username":"asdf","password":"asdf","_token":"mytoken"}:
```

I passed the following object as data:

```
    data = {
        username: 'asdf',
        password: 'asdf',
        _token: 'mytoken'
    };
```

But server ( Laravel ) could not understand request parameters. Please let me know what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `data` should be a `FormData` instance instead of a plain object (which will be json-encoded). Example:

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append("username", "asdf");
data.append("password", "asdf");
data.append("_token", "mytoken");
```