# Laravel can not understand formData parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, httprequest

According to this question:

[Angular5 HttpClient send data but server can not understand its params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986774/angular5-httpclient-send-data-but-server-can-not-understand-its-params)

I send `username`, `password` and `_token` parameters to server through `FormData` in angular5. I set header to

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

now, I faced another problem in server.

Request header changed to

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryGOu5izF9uMKIXDW1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name:"username"

a@a.com
------WebKitFormBoundaryGOu5izF9uMKIXDW1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

123456
------WebKitFormBoundaryGOu5izF9uMKIXDW1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_token"

[object Object]
------WebKitFormBoundaryGOu5izF9uMKIXDW1--
```

Now, Laravel could not read request parameters in this way:

```
$request->input('username') // returns null

$request->input() // returns whole request content, not an object or array
```

How could I read request parameters ?

e.g. Is there any regular expression that can help me? or any patches in higher Laravel versions that I can use?

**Laravel version: 5.2**

Comment: What does your whole function look like in Laravel? Have have make it look like this `myFunction(Request $request, Response $response) { ...` ??

Comment: Can you dump `$request->getContent()`?

Comment: I test it in _handle_ function inside **VerifyCsrfToken** class.

Comment: @NikolaGavric yes, It returns request content, but nut the parameters in array or object.

Comment: Have you just done return $request?

Answer (score 1):

Does your controller in Laravel have these included?

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
```

and does your function look like this?

```
public function signIn(Request $request, Response $response){

    $output = $request->input('username');

    return $output;

}
```

What we are doing above is getting the output of the response which we are wanting username and return that so you should get the username back

**EDIT**

Does your Angular service look like this

```
login(username:string, password:string) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', username);
    formData.append('password', password);
    return this._http.post(
        'http://oauth-api/api/me/signin',
        formData
    );    
}
```

Comment: When I call `$request->input()`, I will get whole the content, not just parameters in array or object. I did all these, but I have no idea how to get POST parameters from request content ..

Comment: @ArezooTaherian Could you make add the angular side? or have you got the code up anywhere?